# Eclipse SVN always includes auto generated bin dir and classes no matter what I do

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

I am using Eclipse Juno with Subversive plugin.

I have a java project set to compile automatically which creates a lot of bin dirs

No matter what pattern i put in window-> preferences->->team->ignored resources, eventually i see the bin dir and all of it's sub dirs in the team synchronizing perspective as new uncommitted files.

I have tried the following syntax:
`*/bin`,`**/bin`, `*/bin/`, `*/bin/*`

No luck.

Also, I have noticed that sometimes if I close eclipse and start it again, the ignored files disappear from the team synchronizing perspective as required, but still, some bin dirs are still present. This whole thing is very inconsistent.

Any idea ?

I have forgot to mention that I am using two worksets, one is the subset of the other, this add buggyness to the whole process appearently

Comment: Have you updated also project preferences?

Comment: @HRgiger no I haven't ? isn't it enough to update only in the global preferences ? What should I update there ?

Comment: sometimes I am having same problem global settings doesnt effect existing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and switched to `Subclipse`. Now everything seems to be working fine, or at least less buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Try the "Subversive SVN JDT Ingnore Extensions". It is located on the [Juno Update Site](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno), under "Collaboration". Its description says:

> The feature is useful for Java development because it allows to automatically interpret output folders as ignored resources.

Seems like exactly what you want. Also, it should work independently of the name of your output folders which is an advantage if you use Maven for example (in that case, your output folders will probably be called `target` and not `bin`).

Comment: It seems that i already have it installed. How do I activate this feature ?

Comment: Weird. I just played around a bit and Eclipse always ignored the output folder, no matter how it is called. And this even worked without the plugin installed. Seems like you're encountering some bugs. In any case, have you tried the simple `bin` pattern?